# Do people in the Star Wars galaxy grow meat in laboratories?

Tags: star-wars, food

I never see them mention lab-grown non-animal meat. I wonder if they even need it since they have a galaxy full of livestock. Am I right?

Comment: I guess absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence, so I can't answer definitively, but yeah -- they seem to have lots of livestock everywhere.  That is a genuinely unique question!

Comment: If video games are lore: Then they kind of do in cloning labs of sort.  In 'Star Wars: Galactic Battlegrounds', there is a building that generates food by putting animals in there.  However, we do see some domesticated animals on naboo, and after all, there must be a nerf that is herded somewhere in the galaxy.

Comment: Lab-grown meat is somewhat of a new thing. I doubt many will have included it in fiction.

Comment: I'd venture that there's not much of a market for it: to the poorest, it would be a luxury. To the middle and upper classes, there's "organic" livestock and wild game. The only other use case I can think of would be dried rations: that'll depend on whether lab meat is really economically more viable.

Comment: @CBredlow I'm not sure. Even in the Legends system, only the plot/lore components of games are accepted as EU canon. Mechanics aren't canon. It's a bit hard to tell how much of that building is canon (I had the game too but lbr it's just a lame Age of Empires knock-off).

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Meat - checked a bunch of links and all seem to point at coming directly from the animal rather than lab grown.